# What is the -u option of compass?

Tags: compass-sass, susy-compass

On the susy site I read,

```
compass create proj -r susy -u susy
```

What is the -u option?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is ruby-compass,

It's a short flag for --update.

See the manual:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/compass.1.html
This should answer any questions about any others.

As for susy, I can't seem to find the docs for it either.
As far as -u in general, it might also be short for --using in other tools.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it is --using.

Comment: I had the feeling it would be, despite what I found.